# Spring REST Error

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to consume a web service that i have created using the `Spring framework` with `REST` `JSON, but I am getting this error:

> ( AVERTISSEMENT: GET request for "http://localhost:8080/ws-dispatcher/contract/typeA" resulted in 404 (Introuvable); invoking error handler
>       Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Introuvable
>           at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:76)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
>           at com.sqli.formation.spring.ws.client.impl.DefaultWebServiceClientImpl.getContract(DefaultWebServiceClientImpl.java:18)
>           at com.sqli.formation.spring.ws.client.AppLauncher.(AppLauncher.java:15)
>           at com.sqli.formation.spring.ws.client.AppLauncher.main(AppLauncher.java:24)

the ServiceImplementation

```
package com.sqli.formation.spring.ws.client.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.sqli.formation.spring.ws.client.IWebServiceClient;
import com.sqli.formation.spring.ws.client.model.Contract;

@Service("defaultWebServiceClient")
public class DefaultWebServiceClientImpl implements IWebServiceClient {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Override
public Contract getContract(String type) {
    Contract c = this.restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://localhost:8080/ws-dispatcher/contract/{type}", Contract.class, type);
    return c;
 }
}
```

this is the Application-context.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sqli.formation.spring.ws"></context:component-scan>


    <!-- Déserialiseur JSON -->
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jacksonConverter"
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    </bean>
```

this is the app launcher :

```
public AppLauncher() {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    IWebServiceClient wsClient = context.getBean("defaultWebServiceClient", IWebServiceClient.class);
    Contract c = wsClient.getContract("typeA");
    System.out.println(c);

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AppLauncher();
}
```

Comment: is a GET call with URL "http://localhost:8080/ws-dispatcher/contract/typeA" works in your browser?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond no because in that controller am only returning the object that its id = "typeA"

Answer (score 0):

Put @PathVariable annotation before the method parameter, so the method looks like

```
@Override
public Contract getContract(@PathVariable String type) {
    Contract c = this.restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://localhost:8080/ws-dispatcher/contract/{type}", Contract.class, type);
    return c;
 }
```